# Golang mutate a struct's field one by one using reflect

Tags: go, reflection

I have a struct like this:

```
type User struct {
    Name   string
    UID    int
    Bio    string
}
```

I have a given instantiated struct, and I want to loop through the fields in that object and modify them one by one.

This is what I have so far

```
user := User{
    Name: "Test",
    UID:  1,
    Bio:  "Test bio",
}

reflectVal := reflect.ValueOf(user)
numFields := reflectVal.NumField()

for i := 0; i < numFields; i++ {
    fieldType := reflect.TypeOf(reflectVal.Field(i))
    reflectVal.Field(i).Set(reflect.Zero(fieldType))
    ...
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflect value is not [addressable](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.CanAddr).  Fix by creating the reflect value from a pointer to the struct.

```
reflectVal := reflect.ValueOf(&user).Elem()
```

Use the following statement to get the field's type. The code in the question gets the type of the reflect.Value, not the type of the value contained within the reflect.Value.

```
fieldType := reflectVal.Field(i).Type()
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0u13Zq7zhPn).